# To update ubuntu "base" or not?

Tags: ubuntu

I'm using `ubuntu` and I love it.  When new releases (12, 13, 14) come out I upgrade to them.  My problem is this - Ubuntu pops up `update` manager window every few days.  I had more than one cases where I updated (mainly `ubuntu base`) and my computer stopped working, or had some major bugs where I had to re install my system overall (another example of such a bug, projector stopped identifying my `VGA out`).  This happened to me too many times.  So my recent workflow is this.

1. Update only 3rd party softwares such as `chrome` and other apps.
2. Do not update `ubuntu base`
3. When a new major ubuntu release comes out re-install the computer.

Is it a known issue that the regular update on a daily basis can cause problems?  Is my workflow correct? am I missing something big?